# NSXMLParser And XML types="html" HTML Encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have my iphone app parsing xml and it is working fine for both the title and date of the feel i am using. However when it comes to parsing the content which happens to be in XML:

The whole XML parses fine and i'm able to use xml elements with the type="text" but type="html" seem to be overlooked as only a '>' appears.

Any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I can tell, there is no way for specifying HTML type for `NSXMLParser` and I don't think using `NSXMLParser` to parse HTML is the right way. I recommend libxml, google for the `htmlSAXParseDoc` for more details.